# Why is my delete button not deleting my database object? Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I cobbled together a delete button and edited my view, it isn't working. Can someone help me fix it?

I've moved some code around and tried some things but I can't get it to work. I need someone to show me what I'm doing wrong.

My view:

```
def post_edit(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Listing, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ListingForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.save()
            return redirect('post_view', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = ListingForm(instance=post)
    if request.POST.get('delete'):
        post.delete()
        return redirect('listings')
    return render(request, 'post_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

My html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Post Edit{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    Hi {{ user.username }}!
    <p><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">logout</a></p>

    <h1>Edit listing:</h1>
    <p>The listing will only be viewable to users if "Is Live" is checked.</p>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
        <p>Click the button below to delete this listing. No second warning is given, once you click delete it will be
            removed.</p>
        <button type="delete" class="delete btn btn-default">delete</button>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"delete"` is not a valid type for an HTML form control. You'l need to change it to `"submit"` (Since you still want to submit the form).

What you'll want to do is create two buttons with the same name, and different values like this:

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
<p>Click the button below to delete this listing. No second warning is given, once you click delete it will be
            removed.</p>
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="delete" class="delete btn btn-default">delete</button>
```

Then you can check in your view if the delete button was clicked, like this:

```
def post_edit(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Listing, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.POST.get('submit') == 'delete':
             post.delete()
             return redirect('listings')
        form = ListingForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.save()
            return redirect('post_view', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = ListingForm(instance=post)
    return render(request, 'post_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

Note that I move the check for the delete button to inside the `if request.method == "POST":` block, for two reasons:

1. You'll only want to check the POST values if it's actually a post method.
2. There is no use editing a post, then deleting it.

Comment: No clue, copied it from a tutorial.

Comment: Upon further inspection, I think it's for when a user does a GET request, to just render the EditForm.

Anyhow, the code I posted should do what you need.